# "while" loop to change interval of "setTimeout" NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I created a rectangle, and I want to give it a speed that changes over time (acceleration).

So I made a "setTimeout" inside a "while" loop.

Supposedly , the "while" loop should continuously change the interval of the "setTimeout" (var=interval) by -1, but instead it replaces it with 1 !!, which makes the rectangle print every 1 milliseconds.

I would like to know why this happens.
the same thing happens if I use the "for" loop.
and I wouldn't mind any other alternative to create acceleration effect.

thank you

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")        

var posX=20;
var posY=20;

var interval = 500;    


function print () {
             
             //background
             
context.fillStyle="black";  
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
             
            //object
            
context.fillStyle="#4286f4";         
context.fillRect(posX, posY, 50, 50);  
                
posX = posX + 1;
posY = posY + 1;
                
        }
            
   
while (interval > 300) {        
         
        interval-- ;
 
 setTimeout(print, interval);
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Particles</title> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    
     
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are creating hundreds of `setTimeout(print, interval);` instances, with each loop iteration!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`  instead.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code consistently and reasonably. (It's a good idea just for yourself, too.)

Answer (score 2):

> the "while" loop should continuously change the interval of the "setTimeout"

No, it schedules a **new** timer at the new interval. The previous one keeps running as well. You very, very, very quickly end up with a **bunch** of timers pending -- which all then expire one right after the next.

Once you start a timer, you can't change when it fires. You can *cancel* it, but you can't change when it fires.

`setTimeout` also schedules a *single* timed callback. If you want repeated ones, use `setInterval` or schedule a new callback from the `setTimeout` callback when it runs.

I recommend taking a step back and experimenting with the basics of timers and intervals before moving on to something complex like doing animations.

Separately: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are the wrong tools for animation, at least in isolation. Instead, when you know you need to update the circle, use `requestAnimationFrame` to have the browser call you immediately before it renders the display (it will fire ~60 times/second, so only request it when you need it). That helps you coordinate with the browser's internal display cycles.

Something along these lines:

```
scheduleNext();

function scheduleNext() {
  if (interval > 300) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        print();
        scheduleNext();
      });
    }, interval);
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

var posX = 20;
var posY = 20;

var interval = 500;


function print() {
  //background
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  //object
  context.fillStyle = "#4286f4";
  context.fillRect(posX, posY, 50, 50);

  posX = posX + 1;
  posY = posY + 1;
}

scheduleNext();

function scheduleNext() {
  if (interval > 300) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        print();
        scheduleNext();
      });
    }, interval);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` doesn't pause the script, it schedules the callback to be run in the given milliseconds. This means that you're scheduling all the callbacks right away, and there's only a 1 millisecond difference between them, which isn't enough to cause an observable difference.

Answer (score 0):

Update :

ahaa , Yes its possible to create the animation loop with just "setTimeout" ,

```js
function test () {
    
print ();     
interval = interval - 10;   
setTimeout(test, interval); 
    
}
    
 test ();
```